# Spring Implementing an AuthenticationListener

Tags: java, spring, security

I am getting very frustrated creating an authenticationFailureHandler. It’s the setup that is killing me. I cannot get the Handler to be fired when the user enters in incorrect login credentials. I think it’s that I am declaring the bean incorrectly but who knows at this point.

I have the following class:

```
public class AuthenticationListener implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ae)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("it gets to the authetificationListener");

    }
}
```

And in my SecurityConfig have the following declaration:

```
@Bean
AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationListener() {
    System.out.println(":: :: It is instantiating a Authentication Failure Handler :: ::");
    return new AuthenticationListener();
}
```

The logs prints this ":: It is instantiating a Authentication Failure Handler ::” but not "it gets to the authetificationListener”. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ultimately, I would like to catch bad credentials so that I can store failed attempts in the database and then force them to reset their password after a certain amount.

Comment: And how do you expect that this would work? Just registering a bean isn't enough, you need to make spring security aware of the fact that you have it and need to wire it up correctly.

Comment: Next to that it is probably easier to create a bean that implements `ApplicationListener`  that listens for [`AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent.html)s instead of implementing an `AuthenticationFailureListener`. That way you just have to define a bean and you will

Comment: I had started with the AuthenticationFailureEvent and it was working pretty well, but what I ultimately want is to redirect them to the password change page, and it seemed like that was not allowed.  I am completely new to Spring and so specifics would be a help.  So if I stay on this track, how do I make spring security aware that I have it?

Comment: Then wire the listener up to Spring Security, simply registering it is going to do nothing it will only take up memory. You need to make the spring security filters aware of the fact that you want to use it. Depending on what you use you either is the `<form-login />` or `loginForm()` to add it.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too early. see my edited comment above. What do I need to do to wire it up to spring security.

Comment: And reading the docs will help to clarify things.